# django deply support LANGUAGES (local vs host)

Tags: python, django, deployment, character-encoding

I was programming my Django site normally .. and I set some data in the database in the Arabic language
it was work find in my locl pc useing pycharm editer
On my local pc its looks like this:
[photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaQX5.jpg)

and then I buy sharing host on Namecheap and deploy my site
after entering some data into my database in the Arabic language
I find it like this!

[photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQyqK.jpg)

It looks like the system Namecheap does not support the language or what!

Answer (score 0):

I fix this
the problem is not from the template or anything it comes from Mysql
I go to PHPMyAdmin and change it :from "latin1" to :COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci